# JavaFXML - Update TableView SQLite

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, fxml, scenebuilder

I have created a TableView in scenebuilder and it is populated with data from a table in SQLiteStudio. I have managed to fill all textfields once the user clicks on a row. The code for that is here:

I have created a update button that is setOnAction. I have tried this code below to allow the users new entry in the textfield to overwrite the original but it is not working. Apparently, my sql query is not correct and I should included something in SQLite database. I just don't know how to do this.

Thank you any help given

Answer (score 1):

Your `update` code sends changes to database only and does not affect TableView. To update TableView you should also set new data to object from TableView like you got old data from it in `fill` but in the opposite direction.

Comment: What happens is, when I click update, the entire table updates to the same characters entered, not just that individual row

Comment: If maybe you could show me with some code, so I could see what It should look like to fix this issue

Comment: @JohnNeel, maybe I misunderstood your problem the first time. So you have some sync mechanism that applies database updates to TableView automatically? To update individual row add WHERE clause in your query.